# Setting up Emacs with swank-js and clojure

Tags: node.js, emacs, clojure, slime

I would like to install slime-js but I already have Clojure installed and it is my understanding that Clojure's current Emacs integration will not work with the version of SLIME  that swank-js uses.  I've tried googling this but keep coming up empty. Has anyone been able to get swank-js and Clojure-mode's nrepl functionality to work well together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're talking about swank-js and swank-clojure? I think nrepl-mode does nothing with SLIME. I installed both via MELPA and everything just work.

swank-js and swank-clojure are two SLIME backends that implement the SLIME's protocol. swank-clojure doesn't support newer version of SLIME, and recently became deprecated. nrepl on the other hand has it's own protocol.

Comment: One thing I did run into was a problem with the version of slime that Emacs' slime-js pulled in.  installing slime-repl 20100404 fixed the issue of --cl-accu-- being void.

Comment: So I updated SLIME and run into this problem too. There's question for this in SO too, and the proper solution is to change `lexical-binding` around the end of `slime.el` to nil. Of course remember to byte-recompile it.